# How do I force 2.4GHz Wi-Fi on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-yosemite, macbook-air, 802.11

I would like to force 2.4GHz Wi-Fi on my MacBook Air because where I am currently everyone is on 5GHz and it has been clogged up so it’s really slow.

Comment: Do both networks have the same SSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force it if your network has the same SSID for both bands. Apple has never provided a tool or even an API for doing this.

Comment: So there is no way to do it at all?

Comment: @DylanLarsen Unfortunately, no. Not from OS X on the built-in Wi-Fi interface. Use a third party Wi-Fi dongle or an alternative OS. Better yet, get the network admins to fix their network.

Comment: The answer is valid for the macOS 11.2.3 as well